# S3 static host redirect and strip slug

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to create a static website redirect rule that redirects `www.domain1.com/* --> www.domain2.com` without maintaining the slug ?

Something like this if wildcard was allowed:

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <KeyPrefixEquals>*</KeyPrefixEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
    <HostName>www.domain2.com</HostName>
    <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
  </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to "think like S3."

"Key prefix" is a *prefix*, and by definition, an empty string is the prefix of all strings -- because `left(anystring,len('')) == ''`.

So you don't need a wildcard -- you should be able to simply say this:

```
<KeyPrefixEquals></KeyPrefixEquals>
```

Then, you don't want to replace the prefix -- you want to replace the entire key, so that looks like this:

```
<ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>
```

You ask... why is it empty instead of `/`?

It's because, in the S3 model, the keyspace does not begin with `/`.  `bucket.example.com/foo` has a path of `/foo` but its key is actually `foo`.

Comment: "think like S3". Exactly