# How to replace the response, not redirect, from an S3 static web site Routing Route?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 buckets can host static web sites, which is very, very useful and cost effective over hosting a full blown server.  It has a feature, where you can specify the index.html, 404.html and redirect rules.  I'm asking about the redirect rules.

Is there a way to replace the key and not redirect?

This example below works.  When the user comes to www.example.com, they are served the index.html page (and the browser's URL isn't changed)  When they request a URL that doesn't exist, the 404.html file is served (and the browser's URL isn't changed) (this is important)

In the example below, I specified a redirect rule.  When the user hits this, the browser's URL is changed.  The `curl` command reveals that S3 sends back a 301 redirect.  OK fine.  That's what the rule says -- (it says `Redirect`)

But I don't want to redirect all the time.  Sometimes I want the URL left alone, but a different page served. (similar to how the 404 page)

Practical Example:

- If a user hits /products/475872.html, I want them to see page 475872.html (this always works)
- If a user hits /products/spiderman-action-figure, I want them to see page 475872.html and I do not want the browser's URL to change.

**This does not seem possible in S3 at the moment.  Is it possible?  That is my question.**

```
{
    "Bucket": "www.example.com",
    "WebsiteConfiguration": {
        "ErrorDocument": {
            "Key": "404.html"
        },
        "IndexDocument": {
            "Suffix": "index.html"
        },
        "RoutingRules": [
            {
                "Condition": {
                    "KeyPrefixEquals": "products/spiderman-action-figure"
                },
                "Redirect": {
                    "ReplaceKeyWith": "475872.html"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300872/s3-static-host-redirect-and-strip-slug)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved it.

Point your S3 bucket to CloudFront and rewrite the request patterns.

[image]

In the path pattern,

> /products/spiderman-action-figure pointing to your origin to
>   /products/475872.html (S3 bucket URL)

The cleaner solution we later followed to modified through code is using Lambda@Edge.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html

[image]

And the Lambda Function request associated with the url origin change request will be `viewer request`.

Implementation sample is covered here.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Path Pattern does not do what you are describing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm using that in production. Point the origin to the S3 bucket location, it will pull the content from S3 bucket and serve in that url.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with S3 routing rules.

They can only be used to generate redirects.